# CMS Made Simple Theme Implementation

Tags: cmsmadesimple

I am newbee to CMS Made Simple. I have HTML for the theme and i want it to implement on my CMS Made Simple site. I don't know how to implement it from FTP. I don't have admin details but have the FTP details only.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Thanks...

Comment: In other words, you don't know how to upload a file to its proper directory via FTP?

Comment: Actually i can't able to find the theme location via FTP, I don't know where the files are stored in directories. I found the css files in tmp/cache directory and it looks like cache files...
Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Pages created in CMS Made Simple are stored and saved to a database. [You have to move your local database](http://docs.cmsmadesimple.org/moving) to your live server. That means in most cases, you will need to log into your server account, and copy the database there.